# FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path [/WebApplicationservlet] -- The module has not been deployed

Tags: netbeans

> Getting this error while creating a project in netbeans

```
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Shubham Misal\Desktop\All Desktop apps\Java\Advanced_Java_J2EE\WebApplicationservlet\build\web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FSHUBHA%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext8004015335841643621.xml&path=/WebApplicationservlet
FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path [/WebApplicationservlet]
C:\Users\Shubham Misal\Desktop\All Desktop apps\Java\Advanced_Java_J2EE\WebApplicationservlet\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1030: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: There was an error due to some tomcat Apache server version  & java ee version so I solved it by using the Apache tomcat 9 version for the server & java ee 7 web version & the web app I was making ran successfully .......:)                                                                                                Hope so it will help ⛅☀️